# React Context API and child component refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a Context component which, when I set a certain value, I'd like them to effect other components using it, but my understanding seems wrong here.

I have a MainComponent component that basically handles the layout of the screen.

```
import { Consumer } from './context';

class MainContainer extends React.Component {


    render() {

        const noPadding = {
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0
          }

        const isAuthenticated = this.context.isAuthenticated()  

        return (
            <HashRouter>
            <Header />
            <Container>
              {isAuthenticated && 
              <AuthorisedArea>
                <Row style={noPadding}>
                  <Col md="3"  style={noPadding}>
                    <RightInfoBar />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md="9">
                      <RouteManager />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </AuthorisedArea>
              }
            </Container>
          </HashRouter>
        )
    }
}

MainContainer.contextType = Consumer;
export default MainContainer
```

This should all work when the user is logged in. When they're logged out, for now, I expect a blank screen, really.

In my Navbar, when a user clicks logout, I do this:

```
 handleLogout() {
      const { toastManager } = this.props;
      const { pathname } = this.props.location;
      this.context.changeAuthenticated(false);
      this.context.logout();

      if(pathname !== "/") {
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }
      toastManager.add('You\'re now logged out', {
        appearance: 'success',
        autoDismiss: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
      });
    }
```

the `this.context.logout` updates a property in my context component, setting 'isAuthenticated' to false.

So my basic context component:

```
const Context = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends React.Component {

    state = {
        user: {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            authStatus : Auth.isAuthenticated()
        },
        changeEmail: (newEmail) => {
            let user = this.state.user;
            user.email = newEmail;
            this.setState({ user: user})
        },
        changeAuthenticated: (newState) => {
            if(newState ===false) Auth.logout();
            let user = this.state.user;
            user.name = "Craig";
            this.setState ({ user: user });
        },
        logout: () => {
            console.log("Will logout");
            Auth.logout();
            this.setState({authStatus: false});
        },
        isAuthenticated: () => {
            return Auth.isAuthenticated()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

So, my main component, I was hoping, would notice that isAuthenticated goes to false... and the screen would go blank (for now... I will do better things once I have this working).

But when I click logout - the console indicates the method in the Context component fired... and the value becomes false... But the screen remains.

Only when I press F5, does the screen go as expected.

How should I be making my `MainComponent` react to React.Context value changes?